# Why is the looking direction often completely wrong while going by bus?

Tags: google-maps, compass

I noticed that the displayed "looking direction" of Google Maps is often (always?) exactly the opposite when I'm going by bus:

[image]

This is astonishing for me, as it is most of the time correct when I'm walking. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

I registered the same phenomenon when going by one type of electric tramway in Prague on my old Motorola phone. It is happening because of strong electromagnetic fields from electric motors. But it happened only when accelerating or decelerating not all times.
Is your bus by any chance equipped with some strong electric engine?